# addEventListener on multiple input file elements

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, addeventlistener, form-data

I have a foreach loop that provides me with multiple (about 5) file input elements.

I got the form to work with a simple submit button, but I would like to get it working without one too (upload when selected).

I get stuck trying to let Js or jQuery react to whichever button is clicked.

My `php` that provides the upload buttons:

```
<?php
  $getCampaign = new Crud();
  $query = "SELECT * FROM `table`";
  $aRow = $getCampaign->getData($query);

  if ($aRow == false){
    echo '<div class="alert alert-danger">No Campaigns!<br/></div>';
  } else { 
    foreach ($aRow as $row) {
      echo '<div class="row marginBottom">';
      echo '<div class="col-sm-2"><strong> '. $row['campaign'] .' </strong></div>';
      echo '<div class="col-sm-5"> '. $row['sort'] .'</div>';
      echo '<div class="col-sm-5">
        <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"  action="process-upload-excel.php">
        <input type="file" id="' . $row['campaign'] . $row['sort'] .'" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">
        <button type="submit" class="addfile">Upload File!</button>
      </form>';
      echo '</div></div>';
  }
<hr/>

  <div id="content">
      <div id="response"></div>
        <ul id="image-list">
        </ul>
  </div>
```

Start of `js` (what I got so far):

```
//Check for FormData
if (window.FormData) {
  formdata = new FormData();
  $(".addfile").css("display", "none");
}

???.addEventListener("change", function (evt) {
  document.getElementById("response").innerHTML = '<i class="fa fa-spinner fa-pulse fa-2x fa-fw"></i><span class="sr-only">Loading...</span>';
// rest of code checking name of file etc.
}
```

I got 'Campaign' and 'Sort' in a DB.

Out of these entries I create the input file elements.
So people can upload the right file for the right Campaign.

But how do I use the addEvenListener the correct way for this example?

I hope someone can educate me.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't see any `input[type=file]` elements.

Comment: Thanks Adam, You are right. I accidently deleted it. Post is edited

Comment: Looks like you want to upload files with ajax ... you can see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2320069/jquery-ajax-file-upload

Comment: well you would need to loop over all the elements and append the event.

Comment: @shushu thanks, that's even better than what I have. I will definately use that. But my problem is with multiple input file elements. If I got 5 file input elements, how do I use it with addEventListener to upload the file (from the clicked input element)directly after selecting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **[delegate](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/)** and do it like this:

**html**

```
<div id="content">

</div>
```

**JS**

```
// Add two uploaders
for (var i = 1; i <= 2; i++) {
  $('#content').append($('<input type="file" id="uploader' + i + '">'));
}

// Add listener for them
$("#content").delegate("input[type=file]", "change", function() {
  alert($(this).attr("id"));
});
```

[**Online demo (Fiddle)**](https://jsfiddle.net/ali_soltani/zvyg9znr/4/)

Comment: @StephanTips It works on all of them. I added a fiddle to my answer. Please see it again.